# Position an image depending on its size

Tags: javascript, html, css

<kbd>**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jcho2017/bcd7usn9/1/)**</kbd>

For the above JSFiddle demo, I need to position the last image so that it is centered, compared to the first three images.

How do I do this?

```
position()

window.onresize = function(event) {
    position();
};

function position(){
    var id = document.getElementById( "imageDisplay" );

    console.log( window.innerWidth );

        if( window.innerWidth > 400 ) {
            console.log( "left" );
                id.style.left = "200px";
                id.style.bottom = 0;
                id.style.top = "20px";
        } else if( window.innerWidth <= 250 ) {
            console.log( "left" );
                id.style.left = "200px";
                id.style.top = "20px";
                id.style.right = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: I've just about got the code above, but I still can't get the last image to center or move to the left a bit.

Should I change the

    console.log( "right" )

to

    console.log( "left" )

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Inside the position function you can write the conditions, refer the `if else if` condition, which checks the window size and determines the position of the element! When the document loads the `position()` function is ran once, to determine the initial position.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Javascript:**

```
position()

window.onresize = function(event) {
    position();
};

function position(){
    var id = document.getElementById("img");
  console.log(window.innerWidth);
  if(window.innerWidth  >800){
  console.log("left");
    id.style.left=0;
    id.style.bottom=0;
    id.style.top="";
  }else if(window.innerWidth  >600){
  console.log("left");
    id.style.left=0;
    id.style.top=0;
    id.style.right="";
  }else if(window.innerWidth < 600){
  console.log("right");
    id.style.right=0;
    id.style.top=0;
    id.style.left="";
  }
}
```

Comment: What do I replace console.log with on my page?

Comment: @CaptSpirk you can ignore that, I Used that for testing if the code works

Comment: How do I put in the JSFiddle Demo link like you did?

Comment: @CaptSpirk Use this syntax [<p><kbd><b>Plunkr Demo</b></kbd></p>]()

Comment: @CaptSpirk Can you replicate the issue you are facing in the JSFiddle I have provided in my answer!, and send it to, I will check the problem!

Comment: I have your code above to bottom of my JavaScript in the JSFiddle example above. I've tried putting it in different sections of the script. 

I just can't get the last image to position correctly, i.e. in the center of the page compared to the others.

I hope the JSFiddle code above is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery I think you would be able to do it.

```
$(window).load( function() {
    //find height only after all elements have loaded
    var widthOfImage = $('#image').width();
    //condition for image
    if(widthOfImage < 200) {
        $('#image').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0
        });
    } else {
        $('#image').css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': 100,
            'left': 100
        });
    }

});
```